# Erro em Update com EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Quado tento atualizar um objeto, no banco, obtenho o erro,

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Neste código:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Editar(Cliente cliente)
{
  if (cliente.Titulo != null)
  {
    db.Entry(cliente.Titulo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Uma tradução para o erro, é:

> A instrução de atualização, inserção ou exclusão da loja afetou um
>   número inesperado de linhas (0). As entidades podem ter sido
>   modificadas ou excluídas desde que as entidades foram carregadas.

Quero saber, o que significa este erro e porque ele está ocorrendo em meu código? Me certifiquei que o objeto sofreu alterações através do `debug` só não entendi porque o *EF* não está conseguindo detecta-las.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro significa que `cliente.Titulo` ainda não existe em banco, então o Entity Framework devolve uma mensagem dizendo que não há objetos com o Id passado no objeto.

Possivelmente o Id está vindo zerado da tela ou vem um valor que ainda não existe como chave.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso (AspNet MVC5) o problema aconteceu porque ao carregar o registro para alteração, não carreguei o campo chave (`Id`) que não era exposto ao usuário.

Para solucionar, usei:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CampoId).
```

Answer (score -3):

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: Benvindo ao Stack Overflow em português! Utilize esta linguagem como padrão neste site.